# Acquia Dev Desktop uses wrong PHP for Drush

Tags: php, drupal, drush, acquia

I have used Acquia Dev Desktop often.  Recently, I have had a problem with Drush.  Even though I selected PHP version 7.2.22 as the default version for my Drupal 8 site, I get an error message that Drush requires a higher version of PHP.  I have attached a screenshot of the terminal. It shows that I am, in fact, running 7.2.22; however, Drush is apparently not seeing it.  Does anyone know what's going on?

The error message reads:

> [preflight] Your command line PHP installation is too old.  Drush
>   requires at least PHP 5.6.0.  To suppress this check, set the
>   enironment variable DRUSH_NO_MIN_PHP=1

[image]

Comment: Did you check the PHP path in your Environmental Variables? Also, in WIndows shell try:  "where php". It shoudl return something like "C:\path-to-devdesktop\DevDesktop\php7_[vers#]_x[#]\php.exe".

Comment: Thanks.  I did use "where php" and it showed that there were two exe files listed, both from acquia dev desktop.  I went into the program folder and renamed the the older php directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\NOTphp5_5_x64"  That broke the path and now everything works properly.  I appreciate the help.